# Get .git directory without cloning down a repository

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I have a very large git repo which takes a while to clone. However I don't need the full repo, I instead want to examine the `.git` repo that gets generated. Is there a way I can get the `.git` folder for this repo without actually cloning it down?

Comment: I don't know if I remember correctly but if I am right then you might want to look into `--bare` and `--mirror` flags of `clone`

Comment: For what it's worth, the `.git` *is* the repo itself; the other stuff is a *work-tree*. The work-tree is not downloaded: it's created from the repo, which is what gets downloaded, with or without `--bare`. Without `--bare`, the repo is downloaded into `.git` and then a commit from that repo is checked out to become your current commit-and-branch. With `--bare`, the repo is downloaded—it's sort of conventional to call the new folder `repo.git` at this point instead of `repo/.git`, but you can use any name you like—and then there is simply no work-tree.

Comment: The `--mirror` flag to `git clone` means: *Make this a bare clone, a la `--bare`, but set it up as a mirror copy of the origin which will overwrite itself with updates from the origin* as opposed to *Set it up as its own repository which can diverge and can accept push operations*. (A mirror is usually not suited for receiving `git push` since it will lose all the pushed commits every time it updates itself from `origin`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean a bare clone

```
git clone --bare
```

It will create the clone without files and the root of the folder will have the contents of the .git folder.

See [docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)